# How do I create a live graph with cpu data in Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, class, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to plot psutil.cpu_percent() as a live graph in Tkinter, but I can't get it to work.
My main problem is getting the cpu_percent to have a "history" and not just plotting one dot every second.

Also I'm not looking to create an ever expanding dataframe with cpu_percent() results as this could be a problem if continually running my script. -So I'm looking to maybe creating some sort of running dataframe loop which purges the oldest entries, or something to that effect.

I'm not picky to what solution is best, as long as the tkinter window displays a live running graph with cpu information in a somewhat fixed interval.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showwarning, askquestion
from tkinter import OptionMenu
from tkinter import StringVar

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from psutil import cpu_percent

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn
from datetime import datetime

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
low_memory=False
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
        
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)


def animate(i):

    cpu_measure = cpu_percent()             
    
    dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
    cpu_time = dateTimeObj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    a.clear()

    a.plot_date(cpu_time, cpu_measure, label='CPU Usage')

    a.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3,
             ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)

    title = "Graph"
    a.set_title(title)


class Analyticsapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {} 
        
        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=
                         "Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Live Plot", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphPage))
        button3.pack(fill='x')


class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Example of Live Plotting", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        
app = Analyticsapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=1000)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you add the import statements to your code, please?

Comment: Full workable code now added. Thanks for the advice. Don't know why I did not do that from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a live graph, you can create lists for the x and y data: `x_data`, `y_data`. Every second, you add a new point at the end of the lists and delete the first one so that you always have the same interval:

```
x_data.append(new_x)
y_data.append(new_y)
x_data = x_data[1:]
Y_data = y_data[1:]
```

From this approach it is quite simple to update the graph using the `set_xdata()` and `set_ydata()` of matplotlib's line object. So if you created your figure with

```
f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
plot = a.plot(x_data, y_data)[0]  # get the line object
```

you can update it using

```
plot.set_xdata(x_data)
plot.set_ydata(y_data)
canvas.draw_idle()  # update display
```

Here is a full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from psutil import cpu_percent
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, nb_points):  
        # nb_points: number of points for the graph
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # matplotlib figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # format the x-axis to show the time
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

        # initial x and y data
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=-nb_points)
        self.x_data = [dateTimeObj + timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(nb_points)]
        self.y_data = [0 for i in range(nb_points)]
        # create the plot
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data, label='CPU')[0]
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Example of Live Plotting")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def animate(self):
        # append new data point to the x and y data
        self.x_data.append(datetime.now())
        self.y_data.append(cpu_percent())
        # remove oldest data point
        self.x_data = self.x_data[1:]
        self.y_data = self.y_data[1:]
        #  update plot data
        self.plot.set_xdata(self.x_data)
        self.plot.set_ydata(self.y_data)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # redraw plot
        self.after(1000, self.animate)  # repeat after 1s


root = tk.Tk()
graph = GraphPage(root, nb_points=1000)
graph.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
root.geometry('500x400')
graph.animate()  # launch the animation
root.mainloop()
```

In the above example, I decided that the matplotlib figure and axes are attributes of the `GraphPage` class and that `animate` is a class method. Also, since I am more familiar with `tkinter` than `matplotlib.animate` I used the `.after(<delay>, <function>)` method to schedule the refreshing of the graph.

**EDIT**: To incorporate this into your code's main structure, you need to add the `controller` argument to the `GraphPage` init method, create the  the "Back" button and start the animation when creating the page. Here is the code (I removed the imports not needed for this example):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from psutil import cpu_percent
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
low_memory = False
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

class Analyticsapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Live Plot",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphPage))
        button3.pack(fill='x')

class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, nb_points=360):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Example of Live Plotting", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='top')

        # matplotlib figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # format the x-axis to show the time
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
        # initial x and y data
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=-nb_points)
        self.x_data = [dateTimeObj + timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(nb_points)]
        self.y_data = [0 for i in range(nb_points)]
        # create the plot
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data, label='CPU')[0]
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack(side='bottom')
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        # append new data point to the x and y data
        self.x_data.append(datetime.now())
        self.y_data.append(cpu_percent())
        # remove oldest data point
        self.x_data = self.x_data[1:]
        self.y_data = self.y_data[1:]
        #  update plot data
        self.plot.set_xdata(self.x_data)
        self.plot.set_ydata(self.y_data)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # redraw plot
        self.after(1000, self.animate)  # repeat after 1s

app = Analyticsapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get this when trying your example. But I'll try and use your examples to fit it to my existing script. Many thanks for your contribution!
```
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-8-733262e4348a> in <module>
>    49 
>     50 root = tk.Tk()
>---> 51 graph = GraphPage(root, maxpoints=1000)
>     52 graph.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
>     53 root.geometry('500x400')
>
>TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maxpoints' `

```

Comment: @Snoozium thanks for the feedback, I renamed a variable just before posting and forgot a few occurrences. The code should work now.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob in working with tkinter.. But i can't seem to get your script to work within my over-arching class analyticsapp, which has "subclasses" where GraphPage is one. I can run it separately, but when combining with my script i fail miserably.

Comment: @Snoozium I have edited my answer to incorporate the graph in your page structure. If you couldn't figure it out by yourself, then you should probably take some time to  look more closely at this structure to understand how the pages are connected.

Comment: You are totally correct about me learning more of how the structure is connected. Thanks a lot for helping -your script is perfect!